# Bootstrap responsive stylesheet breaks span widths?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-system

[image]Busy implementing Twitter Bootstrap with the responsive CSS file included, but this causes issues with my spans. The entire width is supposed to be up to span12, and it follows that 6 * span2 should do the same.

Now here is the funny part. It DOES work if the bootstrap-responsive.css is NOT loaded, but the moment I load the responsive file, the last span floats to the bottom left.

At first I thought it might be my borders around it, but I remove them, and it still floats to the bottom.

```
            <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid green">
                <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid blue">
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
                    <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

It should be possible to load both CSS files and get a decent layout though, right? No?

I am unable to find any other questions that indicate similar results. My Bootstrap CSS files are unmodified, and I do not have my own stylesheet build in yet, therefore I don't think it is something I did wrong.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Kobus

EDIT: Uploaded a screenshot for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code below, it should not be having any issues on using *bootstrap-responsive.css*

```
<div class="row" style="border: 1px solid green">
  <div class="container" style="border: 1px solid blue; width:100%">
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
   <div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="border: 1px solid green">
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid blue">
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Foo!</div>
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Bar!</div>
<div class="span2" style="border: 1px solid red">Baz!</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @RishiKalia, but this does not work. Using the code below giving "container" a width of 100%, breaks the site out of the fixed width. I am not using the container-fluid CSS class - my site is fixed width.

Comment: if it's fixed width then _bootstrap-responsive.css_ is doing the right job..it is moving the exceeded part to next line..imho, you have to rethink on your site design..

Comment: Hi @RishiKalia, this does not make sense to me. Without responsive.css, this does not occur (content fit, window is not resized), with it, it does (content does not fit, extra margin is added, window is not resized). The responsive.css should only resize elements when I resize my screen. My screen is wider than the 940px, so in my opinion nothing should be pushed back to the left, but they should be RESIZED to fit, until it becomes too small to resize, and then all 6 span2 elements will reside below each other.

Comment: you may check the update to my reply above..hope this is what you are trying to get..

Comment: Thank you - the update did the trick!. Now my width is 940px if content fits, and resized accordingly. Thank you